# Draw transparent activity over android application

Tags: c#, android, android-layout, xamarin, android-intent

I'm trying to create an android `Activity` that hooks into the system's `ActionProcessText` intent. The goal is to display my `Activity`'s layout above the currently running application. The `Activity` is starting just fine, but it doesn't show up on top of the running application.

Google Translate does this already and I confirmed it does not have the `Display over other apps` permission.
[image: Google Translate displaying over browser application]
Screen recording showing the above in action - https://i.imgur.com/Q9lVI61.mp4

Here is my activity (written using Xamarin):

```cs
[Activity(Label = "@string/app_name", Exported = true)]
[IntentFilter(new[] { Intent.ActionProcessText, Intent.CategoryDefault }, DataMimeType = "text/plain")]
public class LookupActivity : Activity
{
    public override void OnCreate(Bundle? savedInstanceState, PersistableBundle? persistentState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState);
        var data = this.Intent.GetCharSequenceExtra(Android.Content.Intent.ExtraProcessText);
    }
}
```

and also my layout:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".LookupActivity"
    android:alpha="0.2">
 
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/msg"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
 
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="Button"
        android:onClick="OnButtonClicked"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/msg"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.025" />
 
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

My thinking was that if I set the `Alpha` to something low like `0.2` it would imitate the Google Translate shadow background.

Here is what it looks like when I select my application from the same context menu:
[image: My Application started after selecting from the same context menu]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a style to file `styles.xml` as follows:

```
<style name="AppTheme1" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar">

            <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>

            <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>

            <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>

            <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>

            <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>

            <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>

            <!-- Customize your theme here. -->

            <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>

      </style>
```

And apply it to your activity:

```
 [Activity(Label = "@string/app_name", Exported = true,Theme = "@style/AppTheme1" )]
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was missing. Thank you!